# how to upload any file using dropzone.js in php?

Tags: php, upload, dropzone.js

i am unable to upload image using dropzone.js in php.

i have tried everything but nothing work for me.

MY HTML Code

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="dropzone" id="mydropzone">
        <input type="file" name="img">
        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Upload</button>
</form>
```

MY Javascript Code

```
   Dropzone.options.mydropzone = {
                url:"upload.php",
                uploadMultiple: true,
                maxFilesize: 99,
                maxFiles : 3,
                autoDiscover:false,
                acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
                previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
                autoProcessQueue : false,
                parallelUploads: 100,
                addRemoveLinks: true,       
                init:function(){
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    $("#submitbtn").on('click',function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                       myDropzone.processQueue();
                    });
                }

           }
```

MY PHP Code (I Tried it work 100% fine but with dropzone.js not work)
$upload_dir = "img/";

```
$name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$tmp_file = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir.$name);
```

Comment: What does _"not working"_ mean? Error messages? Have you checked the browsers console to see if you get any JS errors? Have you checked the network tab in your browsers dev tools to see what actually gets passed and what the response is?

Comment: [DropzoneJs + PHP: How to build a file upload form](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add input type file in your html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="dropzone" id="mydropzone">
    <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Upload</button>
```

Try this Code. Hope this will work

```
 var fileList = new Array;
 var i = 0;
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone", { 
     url:"upload.php",
     uploadMultiple: true,
     maxFilesize: 99,
     maxFiles : 3,
     autoDiscover:false,
     acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
     previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
     autoProcessQueue : false,
     parallelUploads: 100,
     addRemoveLinks: true,       
     init:function(){
        this.on("success", function (index, response) {
            var res = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(res);
            fileList = res.images;
            for (i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
              var imgname = fileList[i];
              $(".dz-remove").eq(index).attr('data-url',imgname);
           }
        $('.dz-success-mark').show();
        });
     }
 });
```

In you upload.php file return response with image name

```
  $name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$tmp_file = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$filesCount = count($_FILES[$img]['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) { 
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_file[$i], $upload_dir.$name[$i]);
   $upload_image[] = $name[$i];
}
$response_data=array('images'=>$upload_image);
echo json_encode($response_data);
```

Comment: It will not work. Console error: _Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached._

Comment: Try html code without `form` tag` <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="dropzone dz-square" id="mydropzone"></div>
       </div>`